# Problems booting onto Windows 7 (Dual-Boot Linux / Windows)

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, boot, multi-boot

I have an Acer Aspire 5742G laptop, with Dual-Boot Elementary OS Luna and Windows 7. This installation was created as following:

- First I installed Windows 7 with all the drivers and all the programs I needed (it worked just fine)
- Then I installed Elementary OS Luna.

Everything worked just fine until today. When I opened my laptop, willing to boot into Windows, I noticed that it boot-loops. No Windows logo, no nothing. It just restarts my laptop.

Elementary is still functional and I've been using it for programming, for the last 4-5 hours.

Today, I inserted my Windows 7 install disk, to boot into Recovery. Without any luck, start-up repair says it has no problems :)

I do not want to install Windows 7 again, unfortunately i don't have that much time on my hands.

Update:
Since I use Hiberate not Shut Down, today I deleted the hibernate file using Linux. With no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to boot your computer into the System Recovery Options screen. This is usually done with the installation DVD, which should be inserted into the optical drive. When the computer boots, Press any key to boot from CD or DVD as requested, select your language preference and then click Repair your computer. A list of installed operating systems should be displayed – select Windows 7 and click Next.

The System Recovery Options screen will appear. Select the first option, Use recovery tools that can help fix problems with Windows, and then select Startup Repair.
(If your computer has a pre-installed recovery partition, the process is a little difference. In this case, boot to the Advanced Boot Options screen, select Repair your computer and tap Enter. Next, select the keyboard language type, then your username and password before selecting Startup Repair in the System Recovery Options screen.)
With Startup Repair selected, Windows will attempt to automate the repair; this might work – otherwise, [further actions](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-windows-7-infinite-reboot-loop/) will be required.

Please remember to reinstall grub menu after the previous steps have succesfully completed.

The graphical way:

Insert your Ubuntu live CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
Install and run Boot-Repair

Click "Recommended Repair".
Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

The graphical way
Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
Install and run Boot-Repair

Click "Recommended Repair".
Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.